# Does `-m` argument in `plink.exe` execute local or remote files?

Tags: plink

I was trying to execute this remote file, but I keep getting error as "unable to open command file".

```
plink.exe user@1.2.3.4 -m //localfile/file.txt
```

Will setting argument as `-m` execute the file present in local or remote file system?

Comment: It is a local file and a local name, same as for [putty commandline described here](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.70/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file specified is local but commands from it are executed on the remote side. According to [the manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/plink):

> `-m path`
>   Read remote command(s) from local file `path`.

<sup>(Yes, this is Linux `plink` manual; it's very similar in Windows though).</sup>

Executing a remote script or any other executable is as straightforward as

```
plink.exe user@1.2.3.4 /path/to/executable
```

Some useful examples: [*10 PuTTY PLINK Examples to Automate Remote Linux Commands from Windows Batch Files*](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2017/05/putty-plink-examples/).

Comment: If I want to run a text file containing a  set of linux commands , do I need to change the format to '.sh' to make it run in the terminal of the remote server, I tried , but it doesn't seem to run.

Comment: @senorelanza I think I have answered your original question. If you need help with file extension/format etc. then your should ask a new question. While doing this please be specific: (1) What is the content of the file? (2) What exact command do you use? (3) What is the output and/or error message?